# POSTing modal form data with AJAX to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm a beginner in the world of web programming and I'm in need of some guidance to help me solve a problem.  I apologize that my fundamentals are not very strong at this point.

I have a main page called view.adminsettings.php which I placed a Navigation DIV and a content DIV.  I have a link in the Navigation DIV that loads the content of a 2nd PHP page called view.pdus_1.php into the content DIV of view.adminsettings.php.  On this view.pdu_1.php I have a bootstrap modal popup containing a form in which to submit if the user wants to create another "PDU" in the existing list.  I'd like the user to be able to submit this information via POST to a action.pdu_1.php page that will input the form data to the database.  I'd also like the view.pdu_1.php page to refresh in the content DIV page of the view.adminsettings.php page so that the user can immediately view their newly created item.

My issues are many unfortunately. I'd like help solving the following two issues:

1) I am having trouble getting the data from the form to properly POST to the action.pdu_1.php page. Right now it does both POST (without parameter) and GET. Which page should I post this code?  view.adminsettings.php or view.pdu_1.php?

2) I am also having trouble refreshing the view.pdu_1.php page within the content DIV.  It does not reload the view.pdu_1.php page back into the DIV.

Current code to load view.pdu_1.php page into content div (WORKING):

```
function loadPDUs(){
$(function() {
    $('#DisplayDiv').load('/pdus');
    return false;
});
};
```

HTML snippnet for DIVs in view.adminsettings.php:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row">

    <div id="nav" class="col-md-2"> 

        <h4>Admin Settings</h4>
        <div style="height:20px"></div>
        <p><a href="#" onclick="return loadPDUs();"><i class="fa fa-plug"></i> PDUs </a></p>

    </div>


    <div id="DisplayDiv" class="col-md-10">
        <!-- PDU content here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Sample boostrap modal form code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addpdu">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Add PDU</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="addpdudiv">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <input type="hidden" name="action" id="pduaddaction" value="add">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pduname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pduname" placeholder="PDU Name" name="name">
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <label for="pduports" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ports</label>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pduports" placeholder="Number of ports" name="ports">
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <p class="text-center">
                        <button id="submitpduadd" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button> &nbsp; <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sample AJAX

```
$(function(){
$("button#submitpduadd").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/actions/action.pdu_1.php",
        data: $('form.form-horizontal').serialize(),
        success: function(){
            console.log("submit successful");
            $("#addpdudiv").modal('hide');
            $('#DisplayDiv').load('/pdus');
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("failure");
        }
    });
});
});
```

Sample Action.pdu_1.php Code:

```
<?php
session_start();

$action = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "action");

if($action === "add") {

$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "name");
$ports = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "ports");

$pdu = new pdu();

$pdu->create($name, $ports, $location);

}
?>
```

Comment: Where is the code for /actions/action.pdu_1.php? Since that's what you're posting this data to.

Comment: Hi Twisty, it would be the last sample code I posted (Sample Action.php Code).  I think the formatting was messed up a little.  Basically if one of the variables of the form came back "action: add" (because I'll have multiple forms - add, edit, etc) then take the following actions.  Input POST data into variables, create a new instance of the pdu() object and run the create() function to update the database.  Please let me know if you need more code than already posted.

Comment: Fixed. I ask this cause you're posting to `/actions/action.pdu_1.php` in your AJAX, yet if the file is not the same name, but is `/actions/action.php`, you're posting the data to the wrong page.

Comment: Where is `$location` defined?

Answer (score 0):

I can offer some suggestions. First for the PDU loading:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="nav" class="col-md-2"> 
            <h4>Admin Settings</h4>
            <div style="height:20px"></div>
            <p><a href="/pdus" id="loadPDU"><i class="fa fa-plug"></i> PDUs</a></p>
        </div>
        <div id="DisplayDiv" class="col-md-10">
           <!-- PDU content here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#loadPDU").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#DisplayDiv').load($(this).attr("href"));
    });
});
</script>
```

Just a little more portable and if a browser that does not support  or use JS/JQuery, it will fail back, sort of. You can also then make other links or buttons that can leverage the same code.

Your AJAX code is fine overall. A few small changes can make it more solid and let you know if it's working or dying someplace.

```
$(function(){
    $("button#submitpduadd").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/actions/action.pdu_1.php",
            data: $('form.form-horizontal').serialize(),
            type: 'JSON',
            success: function(retData){
                if(retData.error.length){
                    console.log(retData.error);
                } else {
                    console.log(retData);
                }
                $("#addpdudiv").modal('hide');
                $('#DisplayDiv').load('/pdus');
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("HTTP failure. Try Again.");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The nature of PHP errors will almost always return a 200 status, so AJAX will very rarely get a 400 or 500 status response when making an HTTP Request. You can force it to do so, yet this is time consuming and you can't details back when it fails. This means that `success()` is going to be hit even if PHP encounters an error. Our PHP needs to be able to tell our JS/JQuery that an error was encountered.

```
<?php
session_start();

$action = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "action");
if($action === "add") {
    $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "name");
    $ports = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "ports");
    $location = (isset($_POST['location'])?filter_input(INPUT_POST, "location"):"");
    $params = array("name" => $name, "ports" => $ports, "loc" => $location);
    try {
        $pdu = new pdu();
        $pdu->create($name, $ports, $location);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $error = array('error' => 'Caught exception: ' .  $e->getMessage());
    }
    echo (isset($error))?json_encode($error):json_encode($params));
}
?>
```

So now the PHP will return something even if their is a failure. We can examine that data, success or failure, and figure out whats happening. Even if PHP has a error earlier, the resulting HTML should be view-able using FireBug or other debug tools.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help Twisty.  I've added the modifications to the first bit of code you suggested to the displayDiv and that works great.  The rest of the code still gives me issues however.  I do not see any of the "errors" in the firebug console, however I do see an unknown "out of memory" exception if I include the AJAX code in the view.pdu_1.php page.  If I include the AJAX code in the view.adminsettings.php page, I get no console errors.  Either way the result is the same.. the form information is sent via GET and not POST, which means that the action page never sees it properly.

Comment: Looks like I fixed the POST problem by using your logic.  I used your code Twisty and modified it based on the first function you showed me on view.adminsettings.php.  I changed the AJAX $(submit#submitpduadd).click(function() ) to function(e) and added e.preventtDefault(); which worked.  I also took out the JSON reference.   The Modal.hide and refreshing of view.pdu_1.php into the DisplayDiv content div on the main page are still not functioning.  I'm getting an error telling me $(...).modal is not a function, although I've referenced bootstrap in my PHP.

Comment: Fixed the "$(...).modal" not a function problem.  Typo referencing the ID of the modal.  The modal disappears now, but the darkened background does not go away.  By the way, all this code only works if put on the view.pdu_1.php page and not if put on the view.adminsettings.php page.  Why is that?

Comment: The description for `.load()` is: *Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.*. Any JS/JQuery in that page will not be executed, just the HTML elements are added. So all your functions need to be in the page that calls `.load()`, to be able to work.

Comment: Can you link to a PasteBin or JSFiddle with your current code(s)?